# As a postdoc, I made progress on a project that I was supposed to do during my PhD. I am regretting the time spent on my PhD

Tags: phd, research-process, postdocs, independent-researcher, research-topic

When I joined my computational modeling lab as a PhD student, I was supposed to work on a topic that I was very much interested in.

I spent 2 years of trying, but couldn't show any progress. I became overwhelmed and anxious. My advisor suggested me to change my topic to a completely different direction. At that moment, I was doubting myself, so I agreed and went ahead with the different direction.

Though I found the new direction interesting, it was not what I wanted to do. It was not much challenging and industry relevant. However, I went ahead with it. It still took me 4 more years to complete my PhD with 4 publications.

Now, I have joined my PhD advisor as a postdoc. I started revisiting the abandoned topic last month. I made so much progress in last 15 days that I am confident of producing publishable results by the end of this month.

I am now regretting my time spent during my PhD. I could have worked harder and continued on the topic. I could have completed a much better PhD. I would have gotten much better future prospects.

Comment: While I sympathize with your situation, I am a bit unsure what your question are? Do you have a question?

Comment: What makes you think you would have succeeded if you had stuck to your original topic? Perhaps the freedom from anxiety that you attained after achieving your PhD contributed to your current success. Rejoice in your publishable results!

Comment: @nabla sorry there's no question here. Probably I just wanted to hear some objective comments about this.

Comment: Not a question, so not an answer. The fact that you made progress in two weeks where you were stuck before shows that you didn't waste your PhD time. You learnt and made progress, subconsciously. This is not something that can generally be forced; it is given to one. Now publish strong results, and you should be able to improve your career.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you've learned a lot since your PhD, which is good - it means you've developed as a researcher. I know that at the start of my PhD there are lots of things I could have done better (and in half the time) if I'd known a bit more. But I couldn't do that *then*. I needed to have those experiences in order to improve and learn.

I think you should focus on the fact that you expect to have high-quality publishable results in this area soon. If the better prospects you mention are tied to that topic, you can pursue them once you've published.

Comment: In some ways research is like mushrooms. What we see in the forrest or buy in the market is just the fruiting body. But the organism itself has to live and spread within the soil, sometimes for a long time, before the visible "cap" pops up. Like mushrooms, it is hard to schedule research. Your thinking matured. Be thankful.